# Poisson's equation Evan's book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

I do not understand the line - ' naive differentiation through the integral near the sigularity is unjustified'. I am wondering if anyone could help explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given a function of the form $$u(x) = \int_{{\mathbf R}^n} g(x,y) \, dy$$ it may be tempting to calculate its partial derivatives as
$$\frac {\partial^k}{\partial x_i^k} (x) = \int_{{\mathbf R}^n} \frac {\partial^k}{\partial x_i^k} g(x,y) \, dy.$$

Evans refers to this as *naive* because unless you have a very specific justification for interchanging the integral with the partial derivative (the exchange of an integral with a limiting process typically requires some type of dominated convergence argument) you cannot expect the result to be valid.